# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How to pass environment variables to Docker containers running in AWS Elastic Beanstalk **multiple docker container configuration**(different for different containers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `environment` key in your container descriptions.

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "myContainer",
      "image": "something",
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "MY_DB_PASSWORD",
          "value": "password"
        }
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "memory": 500,
      "cpu": 10
    }]
}
```

For more information, see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html

Comment: thanks, any idea how to define `udp` port mappings in task definitions.