# Using environment variables or .env file in Dockerrun.aws.json for AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, fastapi

Im trying to deploy [this](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/tree/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D) application on an AWS ECS server using Elastic Beanstalk (EB). I'm loosely following [this medium article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-a-multi-container-web-application-aws-elastic-beanstalk-c5f95d266842).

The project is using several environment variables in the docker compose file which are essential for the application. However EB requires Dockerrun.aws.json (equivalent of docker-compose.yml) and one way to add environment variables to Dockerrun json is [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413307/aws-elastic-beanstalk-docker-environment-variables), but I will be passing some credentials to through the environment variables hence exposing those values in the json file will be a security risk.

I have went through the documentation and there wasn't any such feature which allowed the use of environment variable / .env file. Is there a way to add it to the dockerrun file? If not then is there any workaround for using environment variables?

Comment: What kind of application are you running? You can add environment variables through the Elastic Beanstalk console directly on your environment: Environment -> Configuration -> Software, even with Docker.

Comment: Its a web app made with Fast API and docker-compose. When you said that environment variables can be added using Docker. You mean the Dockerrun file?

Comment: No, I meant for secure credentials, you can store them directly on the instance using the Elastic Beanstalk console.

Comment: Alright. Got it. Thanks!